# AT commands to send pictures from Raspberry Pi using SIM900A GSM modem

Tags: python-2.7

I searched everywhere but could not find a proper answer for how to send pictures and other data through the serial ports of the Raspberry Pi 2 through the SIM900A GSM modem.

Comment: You might have better luck on the [Raspberry Pi site](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/). A bit of advice, though... saying something is urgent doesn't usually get you better or quicker answers. Showing what you've tried or what information you've already found (and why it doesn't help) will help you much more. People are typically more willing to help when you show that you've done some significant legwork yourself already.

Comment: I found the code for sending messages from raspberry pi through SIM900A GSM modem but i want to send pictures now. I cant understand how to send the pictures i.e. via message or through MMS and also how to do it. @glibdud

Comment: I implemented the sending message code too @glibdud